# How can I match the content(word, PDF) when creating result type using PowerShell?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, search

I am creating result types using PowerShell. While creating result type how can I match the content of result type?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By using this script you can compare the rules and other things.

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication

$tenantOwner = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchOwner -Level SPWeb -SPWeb "http://URL/search/"    

$ResultType = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchResultItemType -SearchApplication $ssa -Owner $tenantOwner | where-object { $_.Name -eq "Microsoft Word" }

$ResultType2 = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchResultItemType -SearchApplication $ssa -Owner $tenantOwner | where-object { $_.Name -eq "PDF" }

$ResultType.Rules.ToString() -eq $ResultType2.Rules.ToString()
```

Comment: I need to create the result type with match a content field(PDF or Word,..) using powershell